# Data from a nested list gets overwritten without accessing the nested list

Tags: python, dataframe, nested-lists

I've been trying to pass some information from a Pandas DataFrame into diferent lists, a list for the DateTime values and one for the values (only ones and zeros) that will be passed to a nested list. There are no error messages, but the script is not doing as I wish. It is overwritting the nested list when I try to reset the values list (from a number to "") which is passed to the nested one. I'm relatively new to Python and couldn't figure out why this is happening. The code is as it follows:

```
def work_that_data ():
val = ["" for addrs in list_of_adds_B] ## Here I need to put the data in the correct position, and list_of_adds_B is a list of strings to pass as columns, which relates to the binary data that will be stored
ind_list = [] ## A list to store the indexes (DateTime values)
col_list = [addrs for addrs in list_of_adds_B] ## All the names to be used as columns
list_of_lists = [] ## Here there will be a list for each DateTime index
interval = check_int() ## A simple interval check, which divides the day in two intervals, returning 1 or 2
for loop_cont in range(len(list_of_adds_B)): ## A for loop, looping through every string stored in list_of_adds_B as indexes (integers)
    df_list = foo() ## List of a single DataFrame generated from certain functions. The DataFrame is accessed using df_list[0] and has only 2 columns, column '0' is the DateTime and '1' is the binary value
    if len(df_list) == 0: ## In case the list comes empty
        continue
    for lin_cont in range(df_list[0].shape[0]): ## Looping through all the lines in the DataFrame
        dt_df = datetime.datetime.strptime(df_list[0].at[lin_cont, 0], '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S') ## The DateTime comes as strings, so I need to convert them
        if interval == 1:
            if check_dt(dt_df) == 1: ## Another interval check, to see if the DateTime stored in the DataFrame belongs in the interval.
                if dt_df in ind_list: ## Checking if this DateTime value is already stored in the index list, and if so, update the nested list at the right place
                    index_ind = ind_list.index(dt_df)
                    list_of_lists[index_ind][loop_cont] = df_list[0].at[lin_cont, 1]
                else:
                    ind_list.append(dt_df) ## If it's not stored, it is appended
                    val[loop_cont] = df_list[0].at[lin_cont, 1] ## The values list is updated at the correct index with the value from the DataFrame column '1' 
                    list_of_lists.append(val) ## Values list is appended, stored in the same index as its DateTime value
                    val[loop_cont] = "" ## ERROR HERE!! When I get to this part, I tried to reset the values list (making the value become "") so it can be reused with other addresses without any data previously stored, since it needs to be updated at a certain index and would be updated if dt_df was already located in ind_list, but instead, the nested list gets updated as well.
```

The rest of the code is the basicaly the same, but checking for interval == 2. I'm sorry if it's a bit messy, but the data I'm working with is an absolute mess, and I'm just trying to make this work as soon as possible. Would really appreciate if someone could help me out, since I get no Error messages but can't seem to figure out what's wrong here, and I was able to identify that this `val[loop_cont] = ""` is where it all goes south.

Here's an example of a DataFrame used:

| i | 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021/11/25 16:23:07 | 0 |
| 1 | 2021/11/25 16:47:05 | 1 |
| 2 | 2021/11/25 17:24:07 | 0 |
| 3 | 2021/11/25 17:48:35 | 1 |
| 4 | 2021/11/25 18:23:07 | 0 |
| 5 | 2021/11/25 18:47:04 | 1 |
| 6 | 2021/11/25 19:31:07 | 0 |
| 7 | 2021/11/25 20:00:28 | 1 |
| 8 | 2021/11/25 20:38:07 | 0 |
| 9 | 2021/11/25 21:15:33 | 1 |
| 10 | 2021/11/25 21:45:07 | 0 |
| 11 | 2021/11/25 22:38:43 | 1 |
| 12 | 2021/11/25 23:07:07 | 0 |
| 13 | 2021/11/25 23:53:02 | 1 |
| 14 | 2021/11/26 00:21:07 | 0 |
| 15 | 2021/11/26 01:00:32 | 1 |
| 16 | 2021/11/26 01:27:07 | 0 |
| 17 | 2021/11/26 02:21:35 | 1 |
| 18 | 2021/11/26 02:45:07 | 0 |
| 19 | 2021/11/26 03:40:13 | 1 |
| 20 | 2021/11/26 04:06:07 | 0 |
| 21 | 2021/11/26 05:05:28 | 1 |
| 22 | 2021/11/26 05:28:07 | 0 |
| 23 | 2021/11/26 06:27:49 | 1 |
| 24 | 2021/11/26 06:57:06 | 0 |
| 25 | 2021/11/26 07:35:33 | 1 |
| 26 | 2021/11/26 08:05:07 | 0 |
| 27 | 2021/11/26 08:36:33 | 1 |
| 28 | 2021/11/26 09:16:07 | 0 |
| 29 | 2021/11/26 09:40:32 | 1 |

Comment: Ideally when asking questions, you pinpoint a minimum reproducible code snippet/example so that people can see what's wrong. So keep that in mind in the future!

Answer (score 0):

In the last branch of the code, you do something like:

```
ind_list.append(dt_df) 
val[loop_cont] = df_list[0].at[lin_cont, 1] 
list_of_lists.append(val) 
val[loop_cont] = ""
```

Let's walk through what this does:

1. You append `dt_df` to `int_list`
2. Then you set the the `loop_cont` index of `val` to be `df_list[0].at[lin_cont, 1]`
3. Then you append `val` to `list_of_lists`
4. And then you finally set the `loop_cont` index of `val` to `""`.

Step 4. overwrites what you did in step 2. Python is an Object Oriented Language, which means that structures in Python are objects and have references. Since you never create a new list for the values, `val` will always reference the same list that you originally created, so your `list_of_lists` will only end up containing the same list object over and over again, which means that everything will be the same. What I think you might want to do instead is:

```
ind_list.append(dt_df) 
val[loop_cont] = df_list[0].at[lin_cont, 1] 
list_of_lists.append(val) 
val = ["" for addrs in list_of_adds_B]
```

So that `val` references a new list and the lists will be different going forward.